# Bootstrap 4 / Popper.js interfering with Autosuggestions

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4, popper.js, smartystreets

I have a feature that does address verification with smartystreets api I am also using a template with bootstrap4 / popper.js and jquery of course.

If you click both links, you will see the behavior.  It will either break the address verification plugin or the design, but I cant figure out how to make them both work together.

The difference between the two is that one has class="form-control" whereas the other one does not.  Something with the form-control class is triggering the behavior.  The broken design link shows error in the console and aborts whatever process causes "display:none" to be added so the address suggestions work.

If I dont trigger that error, the address verification plugin removes the "display:none" but its immediately followed by something else in bootstrap or popper.js interfering and changing it back to display:none giving it just a blinking effect.

If anyone could take a closer look and point me in the right general direction.

Comment: I managed to fix it myself by uncommenting out lines 6285-6304 in the bootstrap-material-design.js file.  I'm not sure what the intention was for that portion of code but if anyone has a better solution let me know.  I'll mark my own answer since it seems to be attracting very little attention anyhow and I won't be leaving the link up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if anyone else is using a template that contains autofill.js in the sourcemap of the material-design-bootstrap.js above just comment out this portion of the script as I mentioned above and it will work.  Its a hack, not really an answer but it didnt seem to affect any other functionality as far as I could tell.